# What is the difference between Go's multithreading and pthread or Java Threads?

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, pthreads, go

What is the difference between Go's multithreading approach and other approaches, such as pthread, boost::thread or Java Threads?

Comment: I believe it is the "multithreading facilities as a whole" that is of interest here.

Comment: It's been only couple of days since they announced it, and there are already about 70 questions about go... Power of Google.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Quoted from [Day 3 Tutorial](https://git.ustclug.org/zhsso/go/blob/fa3d86ca39f9d168f194b232538794bd09f887f3/doc/GoCourseDay3.pdf) <- read this for more information.

> Goroutines are multiplexed as needed
>   onto system threads. When a goroutine
>   executes a blocking system call, no
>   other goroutine is blocked.
>
> We will do the same for CPU-bound
>   goroutines at some point, but for now,
>   if you want user-level parallelism you
>   must set $GOMAXPROCS. or call
>   runtime.GOMAXPROCS(n).

A goroutine does not necessarily correspond to an OS thread. It can have smaller initial stack size and the stack will grow as needed.

Multiple gorouitines may be multiplexed into a single thread when needed.

More importantly, the concept is as outlined above, that a goroutine is a sequential program that may block itself but does not block other goroutines.

Goroutines is implemented as pthreads in gccgo, so it can be identical to OS thread, too.
It's separating the concept of OS thread and our thinking of multithreading when programming.

Comment: Broken link to tutorial - looks like http://go.googlecode.com/hg-history/release-branch.r60/doc/GoCourseDay3.pdf may be it.

Answer (score 13):

IMO, what makes the multi-threading in Go appealing is the communication facilities: unlike pthread where one must build the communications infrastructure (mutex, queues etc.), in Go it is available by default in a convenient form.

In short, there is **"low-friction" to using threads because of the good communication** facilities (akin to Erlang if I can say so).

Answer (score 12):

In the reference compilers (5g/6g/8g), the master scheduler ([src/pkg/runtime/proc.c](http://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c)) creates N OS threads, where N is controlled by runtime.GOMAXPROCS(n) (default 1). Each scheduler thread pulls a new goroutine off the master list and starts running it. The goroutine(s) will continue to run until a syscall is made (e.g. printf) or an operation on a channel is made, at which point the scheduler will grab the next goroutine and run it from the point at which it left off (see gosched() calls in [src/pkg/runtime/chan.c](http://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/chan.c)).

The scheduling, for all intents and purposes, is implemented with [coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine). The same functionality could be written in straight C using setjmp() and longjmp(), Go (and other languages that implement lightweight/green threads) are just automating the process for you.

The upside to lightweight threads is since it's all userspace, creating a "thread" is very cheap (allocating a small default stack) and can be very efficient due to the inherent structure of how the threads talk to eachother. The downside is that they are not true threads which means a single lightweight thread can block the entire program, even when it appears all the threads should be running concurrently.

Comment: Has there been any update made to this implementation since the time you answered this?

Comment: proc.c no longer exists as it looks like the Go compiler is now self hosting: https://golang.org/src/runtime/proc.go

Answer (score 5):

As previous answers have stated, go routines do not necessarily correspond to system threads however I found the following useful if you must have the performance increase of multi-threading right now:

> **The current implementation of the Go runtime will not parallelize** this code by default. It dedicates only a single core to user-level processing. An arbitrary number of goroutines can be blocked in system calls, but by default only one can be executing user-level code at any time. It should be smarter and **one day it will be smarter**, but until it is **if you want CPU parallelism you must tell the run-time how many goroutines you want executing code simultaneously**. There are two related ways to do this. Either run your job with environment variable GOMAXPROCS set to the number of cores to use or import the runtime package and call runtime.GOMAXPROCS(NCPU). A helpful value might be runtime.NumCPU(), which reports the number of logical CPUs on the local machine. Again, this requirement is expected to be retired as the scheduling and run-time improve.

[quote source](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#parallel)

An example program that maxes out my i5 processor is this (uses all 4 cores at 100% in htop):

```
package main


import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "runtime"
)


func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4) // Set the maximum number of threads/processes

    d := make(chan string)
    go boring("boring!", d, 1)
    go boring("boring!", d, 2)
    go boring("boring!", d, 3)
    go boring("boring!", d, 4)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        time.Sleep(time.Second);
    }

    fmt.Println("You're boring; I'm leaving.")
}

func boring(msg string, c chan string, id int) {
    for i := 0; ; i++ {

    }
}
```

Now that doesn't actually 'do' anything, but see how short/easy/simple that is compared to writing multithreaded applications in other languages such as Java.

Comment: The example you gave in Go is just as simple to write in Java the only difference is that in Java you can't assign them to a specific core because threads are handled by the JVM so please correct your answer.

Comment: @RaduSebastianLAZIN I realize my statement that "see how short/easy/simple that is compared to writing multithreaded applications in other languages such as Java" is quite subjective. Please feel free to link a comparison Java codebase that demonstrates Java is just as short/simple.

Comment: sure, here it is: https://github.com/raduking/java-tests/blob/master/src/SimpleThreads.java

Comment: [And even simpler in Java 21](https://github.com/raduking/java-tests/blob/master/src/SimpleThreadsJava21.java) (which will be released in September this year)